# Assigning a variable the result of a fetch function

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm just now sure why this isn't working. I've also tried an async/await solution, but in all cases, the `variable` doesn't have the data assigned to it.

```
let variable = []

let getProducts = () => {
  return fetch(baseUrl + limitUrlModifier + pageUrlModifier + toString(pageNumber) + includeFieldsUrlModifier, getFetchOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => variable = data.data)
}

getProducts()
```

Comment: It will eventually... when are you trying to access it? Are calling `.then` on the promise returned by getProducts so that you wait for the promise to resolve?

Comment: @NicholasTower I thought that was the point of the function in the .then, to resolve and then continue?

Comment: Well to achieve that you should use `async` and `await`. But again that is async function. Anything accessing it, should again async await or .`then` to resolve.

Comment: So if I do something like 
```let runScript = () => {
  async () => {
    productList = await getProducts()
  }
  console.log(productList.length)
}```

It shows 0 for length even with 2 items in the array later in the script.

Comment: ... cause you never call the async function expression you've built up, also the log should be inside of it ...

Comment: `I thought that was the point of the function in the .then, to resolve and then continue?` Basically yes, but the code that does the continuing needs to be in the function. If the only thing you're doing in the function is assigning to a variable, it's not very useful. So the code that actually uses `variable` needs to be in the .then callback, at which point, there's little reason to have `variable` at all